# Appending lists by multiplying values by a non-constant variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, append

INPUT:

```
npv_cashflows_list = []
for i in overall_cashflow_list:
    npv_cashflows_list.append(i/(1+data.interest) ** (year))

print(npv_list)
```

OUTPUT:

```
9045347.58895201, 9045347.58895201, 9045347.58895201, 9045347.58895201, 9045347.58895201, 10929795.003317012, 13191131.900555015, 15904736.177240614, 19161061.30926334, 23068651.467690602, 27776604.13194697, 33403533.960082237, 40155849.75384455, 48258628.706359334, 57981963.44937707, 69631120.6668547, 83632722.69680025, 100434645.13273488, 120596952.05585644, 144791720.36360234]
```

EXPLANATION:

I have a list of values (overall_cashflows_list) that I would like to use to create another list (npv_cashflows_list). I wish to divide each value from the overall_cashflows_list by a factor of '1+data.interest' ** year(1-20)
However, my current code just applies the value of 20 (the last year in the list) to each exponent. Instead I need the exponent of the first equation for the first cashflow to be 1, the exponent for the 5th equation to the power of 5, and so on. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is `year` coming from? Can you show us what is in `overall_cashflow_list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate()` to get the element and index from `overall_cashflow_list`.

```
for year, i in enumerate(overall_cashflow_list):
    npv_cashflows_list.append(i/(1+data.interest) ** (year+1))
```

Since list indexes start at `0`, you need to add 1 to make the exponents start at `1`.